# html 5 pattern doesnt work when master page is attached to it

Tags: asp.net, html

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="zzzz.aspx.cs" Inherits="zzzz" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="zzzz" Runat="Server">

<div class="form-group">
  Country code: <input type="text" required="required"  name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code"  class="form-group">

</div>
<input type="submit" class="form-group">
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>


</asp:Content>
```

Here pattern doesnt work i dont know why.. i tried all possible way to bring it, nothing helped me . I wanted to use patter to filter special character in the textbox. Please help me on this issue.. thank you..

Comment: Click the submit button then you will get a title as a message (Three letter country code)

Answer (score 0):

It is working properly.

However, if you are running this page on IE, check what mode the browser is in. Simply press F12 and make sure it is set to IE10/Standard.

And if this is indeed the case, add/modify the following line to your Site.master:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

And this will fix this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Johnny... I am using chrome latest version browser and i can get the error message.. Pattern works and return as invalid, so i am using css to display error styles but i want to make a error to be displayed in words in the bottom...

Comment: What you want to do now has nothing to do with your original question. Does it? And as to Chrome, I am afraid the error message "Three letter country code" is not controllable by css. It will stay where the browser sees fit. If you want to manually control the error messages, you may want to use ASP.NET Validation Controls instead (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its working perfectly

```
<html>
<body>    
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Enter invalid country code and click submit button. Then You can get a message (title="Three letter country code")

Comment: thanks golda.. These code works when i just simply use html ... But in my code when binding master page it doesnt worked..